# Writing a value on the flash memory in C

Tags: c, embedded, nxp-microcontroller

Currently I am trying to write a short string on the flash memory of the microcontroller I am using. The goal would be that the program writes the firmware version at a specific address so that the bootloader can read this and check if there is an update. The driver example provided by NXP seems to work (I can write and read the variable). However, when I place this code on my program I get error 103  `kStatus_FTFx_AccessError` when running `FLASH_Erase` and the next functions. Which to my understanding means that the address I set is not correct.

This is my memory map (linker file):

```
MEMORY
{
  m_interrupts          (RX)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x00000400
  m_flash_config        (RX)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000400, LENGTH = 0x00002000
  m_text                (RX)  : ORIGIN = 0x00005000, LENGTH = 0x001FFBF0
  m_data                (RW)  : ORIGIN = 0x1FFF0000, LENGTH = 0x00030000
  m_data_2              (RW)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00030000
}
```

The function I am running:

```
#include "FlashStorage.h"
#include "fsl_device_registers.h"
#include "fsl_debug_console.h"
#include "board.h"
#include "clock_config.h"
#include "fsl_flash.h"
#if defined(FSL_FEATURE_HAS_L1CACHE) && FSL_FEATURE_HAS_L1CACHE
#include "fsl_cache.h"
#endif /* FSL_FEATURE_HAS_L1CACHE */
#include "pin_mux.h"


#define BUFFER_LEN 4


/*! @brief Flash driver Structure */
static flash_config_t s_flashDriver;
/*! @brief Flash cache driver Structure */
static ftfx_cache_config_t s_cacheDriver;
/*! @brief Buffer for program */
static uint32_t s_buffer[BUFFER_LEN];
/*! @brief Buffer for readback */
static uint32_t s_buffer_rbc[BUFFER_LEN];


/***********************************************************************/
/* LOCAL FUNCTION PROTOTYPES                                           */
/***********************************************************************/


/***********************************************************************/
/* GLOBAL FUNCTIONS                                                    */
/***********************************************************************/
void FLASH_WriteFlashMemory(void)
{
    ftfx_security_state_t securityStatus = kFTFx_SecurityStateNotSecure; /* Return protection status */
    status_t result;    /* Return code from each flash driver function */
    uint32_t destAdrss; /* Address of the target location */
    uint32_t i, failAddr, failDat;

    uint32_t pflashBlockBase = 0;
    uint32_t pflashTotalSize = 0;
    uint32_t pflashSectorSize = 0;

    memset(&s_flashDriver, 0, sizeof(flash_config_t));
    memset(&s_cacheDriver, 0, sizeof(ftfx_cache_config_t));
    result = FLASH_Init(&s_flashDriver);
    if (kStatus_FTFx_Success != result)
    {
        PRINTF("error " );         //error_trap();

        //error_trap();
    }
    /* Setup flash cache driver structure for device and initialize variables. */
    result = FTFx_CACHE_Init(&s_cacheDriver);
    if (kStatus_FTFx_Success != result)
    {
        PRINTF("error " );         //error_trap();

        //error_trap();
    }
    /* Get flash properties*/
    FLASH_GetProperty(&s_flashDriver, kFLASH_PropertyPflash0BlockBaseAddr, &pflashBlockBase);
    FLASH_GetProperty(&s_flashDriver, kFLASH_PropertyPflash0TotalSize, &pflashTotalSize);
    FLASH_GetProperty(&s_flashDriver, kFLASH_PropertyPflash0SectorSize, &pflashSectorSize);

    /* Check security status. */
    result = FLASH_GetSecurityState(&s_flashDriver, &securityStatus);
    if (kStatus_FTFx_Success != result)
    {
        PRINTF("error " );         //error_trap();

        //error_trap();
    }
    /* Test pflash basic opeation only if flash is unsecure. */
    if (kFTFx_SecurityStateNotSecure == securityStatus)
    {
        /* Pre-preparation work about flash Cache/Prefetch/Speculation. */
        FTFx_CACHE_ClearCachePrefetchSpeculation(&s_cacheDriver, true);

        /* Debug message for user. */
        /* Erase several sectors on upper pflash block where there is no code */
        PRINTF("\r\n Erase a sector of flash");

/* In case of the protected sectors at the end of the pFlash just select
the block from the end of pFlash to be used for operations
SECTOR_INDEX_FROM_END = 1 means the last sector,
SECTOR_INDEX_FROM_END = 2 means (the last sector - 1) ...
in case of FSL_FEATURE_FLASH_HAS_PFLASH_BLOCK_SWAP it is
SECTOR_INDEX_FROM_END = 1 means the last 2 sectors with width of 2 sectors,
SECTOR_INDEX_FROM_END = 2 means the last 4 sectors back
with width of 2 sectors ...
*/
#ifndef SECTOR_INDEX_FROM_END
  #define SECTOR_INDEX_FROM_END 1U
#endif

        destAdrss = 0x2400  ;
        result = FLASH_Erase(&s_flashDriver, destAdrss, pflashSectorSize, kFTFx_ApiEraseKey);
        if (kStatus_FTFx_Success != result)
        {
            PRINTF("error " );         //error_trap();

            //error_trap();
        }

        /* Verify sector if it's been erased. */
        result = FLASH_VerifyErase(&s_flashDriver, destAdrss, pflashSectorSize, kFTFx_MarginValueUser);
        if (kStatus_FTFx_Success != result)
        {
            PRINTF("error " );         //error_trap();

            //error_trap();
        }

        /* Print message for user. */
        PRINTF("\r\n Successfully Erased Sector 0x%x -> 0x%x\r\n", destAdrss, (destAdrss + pflashSectorSize));

        /* Print message for user. */
        PRINTF("\r\n Program a buffer to a sector of flash ");
        /* Prepare user buffer. */
        for (i = 0; i < BUFFER_LEN; i++)
        {
            s_buffer[i] = 3;
        }

        /* Program user buffer into flash*/
        result = FLASH_Program(&s_flashDriver, destAdrss, (uint8_t *)s_buffer, sizeof(s_buffer));
        if (kStatus_FTFx_Success != result)
        {
            PRINTF("error " );         //error_trap();

            //error_trap();
        }

        /* Verify programming by Program Check command with user margin levels */
        result = FLASH_VerifyProgram(&s_flashDriver, destAdrss, sizeof(s_buffer), (const uint8_t *)s_buffer, kFTFx_MarginValueUser,
                                     &failAddr, &failDat);
        if (kStatus_FTFx_Success != result)
        {
            PRINTF("error " );         //error_trap();
        }

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < BUFFER_LEN; i++)
                {
                    s_buffer_rbc[i] = *(volatile uint32_t *)(destAdrss + i * 4);
                    if (s_buffer_rbc[i] != s_buffer[i])
                    {
//                        error_trap();
                    }

                    PRINTF("\r\n VALUES: %d, %d, %d, %d ",s_buffer_rbc[0], s_buffer_rbc[1], s_buffer_rbc[2], s_buffer_rbc[3] );
                }

        /* Post-preparation work about flash Cache/Prefetch/Speculation. */
        FTFx_CACHE_ClearCachePrefetchSpeculation(&s_cacheDriver, false);

#if defined(FSL_FEATURE_HAS_L1CACHE) && FSL_FEATURE_HAS_L1CACHE
        L1CACHE_InvalidateCodeCache();
#endif /* FSL_FEATURE_HAS_L1CACHE */

#if defined(__DCACHE_PRESENT) && __DCACHE_PRESENT
        /* Clean the D-Cache before reading the flash data*/
        SCB_CleanInvalidateDCache();
#endif

    }
    else
    {
        PRINTF("\r\n Erase/Program operation will not be executed, as Flash is SECURE!");
    }

}
```

How can I prepare the memory to be suitable to be written? Or what would be a suitable address on where to write? I don't seem to understand why the memory address I am using is incorrect since it is not used in the memory map.

HW and compiler:

- Microcontroller: K66F Development board by NXP.
- Kinetis design studio IDE.
- GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors (arm-none-eabi-gcc)

Comment: Which MCU? Which compiler?

Comment: There might be some king of erase/prog protection that you need to unlock. Don't know what MCU you're working on but it is common.

Comment: Probably you should check flash controller status register for precise hardware error code. And then look in documentation what does it mean. The error code you get looks like some software generalization

Comment: This is an X-Y problem - you are asking about a problem with your solution rather then about the problem you are trying to solve.  Do you really want to use an entire flash erase block for that?  Better to embed the version number as a constant string at a known location in your code using whatever linker directives your toolchain supports for that.  The linker will then have knowledge of the fixed location string and can efficiently locate other code and data around it.  The version then  is specified in the build, not added manually after - which would be error prone.

Comment: Here's how you do it with gcc: https://mcuoneclipse.com/2012/11/01/defining-variables-at-absolute-addresses-with-gcc/.  Though in your case you'll want something like: `static const char __attribute__((section (".BootInfoSection"))) versionstr[16] = "01.01.01" ;`

Comment: @Clifford I wrote what you propose and modified the linker file as stated on the link. I checked and the variable is indeed in the memory address I want it to be, but the variable shows up as 0. The whole buffer is 0. Would you know why this happens? I tried to set the type to int and the variable was set to 0 also.

Comment: @Asan : Different problem, different question.  Post a new one.  You'll do better with a broader audience that just asking me, and you will be able to show _exactly_ what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because your erase/program function is running from flash. The controller doesn't allow the flash to be erased/programmed when executing from flash. As a solution, you can copy the flash routine to RAM and execute from there.

To make sure if that is the case, please have a look at your map file and check the address of flash routines.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable -- and rather hidden -- difference between your project and the demo application is the mode that the MCU is running in.

Per the reference manual:

[image: high speed run mode restrictions]

The demo app runs in RUN mode, your project is most likely in HSRUN. The solution is to either use RUN mode from the start (set in `BOARD_InitBootClocks()`, check clock configuration tool), or switch to RUN mode before erasing and programming the flash, and then switch back:

```c
status_t result = 0;

// erasing
SMC_SetPowerModeRun(SMC);
while (SMC_GetPowerModeState(SMC) != kSMC_PowerStateRun) {}

result = FLASH_Erase(&flash_driver, FLASH_ADDR, FLASH_SECTOR_SIZE, kFLASH_ApiEraseKey);
if (result != kStatus_Success) {
    // error handling
    goto exit;
}

// programming
result = FLASH_Program(&flash_driver, FLASH_ADDR, (uint8_t *) &data, sizeof(data));
if (result != kStatus_Success) {
    // error handling
    goto exit;
}

exit:
SMC_SetPowerModeHsrun(SMC);
while (SMC_GetPowerModeState(SMC) != kSMC_PowerStateHsrun) {}
```

It is pretty unfortunate that the in-code documentation doesn't state this; instead it is quite misleading:

> @retval #kStatus_FTFx_AccessError Invalid instruction codes and out-of bounds addresses.